# Amcharts angular : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Directive' of undefined

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am trying to integrate AmCharts library with my Angular-seed application of Mgechev [Here is the link.](https://github.com/adityashukla74/amcharts-with-angular2)

Here is the error which I get in Terminal:

> ERROR: /Users/adityashukla/Documents/Code/github/amcharts-with-angular2/src/client/app/about/about.component.ts[24, 2]: Implement lifecycle hook interface OnInit for method ngOnInit in class AboutComponent

And this is what I am getting in Chrome Console :

```
app.js?1498467214338:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Directive' of undefined
```

Below is the Code :

about.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AmChartsService } from '@amcharts/amcharts3-angular';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'sd-about',
templateUrl: 'about.component.html',
styleUrls: ['about.component.css']
})
export class AboutComponent {
private timer: any;
private chart: any;
constructor(private AmCharts: AmChartsService) { }
var dataProvider = [];
for (var year = 1950; year <= 2005; ++year) {
dataProvider.push({
year: '' + year,
value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) - 50
});
}


return dataProvider;
}
ngOnInit() {
this.chart = this.AmCharts.makeChart(
'chartdiv', {
'type': 'pie',
'theme': 'light',
'dataProvider': [
{
'title': 'New', 'value': 4852
},
{
'title': 'Returning',
'value': 9899
}
],
'titleField': 'title',
'valueField': 'value',
'labelRadius': 5,
'innerRadius': '60%',
'labelText': '[[title]]',
}
);
}
}
```

about.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AboutRoutingModule } from './about-routing.module';
import { AmChartsModule } from '@amcharts/amcharts3-angular';

@NgModule({
imports: [CommonModule, AboutRoutingModule, AmChartsModule],
declarations: [AboutComponent],
exports: [AboutComponent]
})
export class AboutModule { }
```

> When I try to run > npm run start.deving
>   Chart is displaying but with an error in Console

```
 404: /base/node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts3-angular/umd/index.js
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
"dependencies": {  
"@amcharts/amcharts3-angular": "^1.2.1"  
}
```

I have already mapped Amcharts umd like this in SeedConfig aka SystemJS

```
SYSTEM_CONFIG: any = this.SYSTEM_CONFIG_DEV;  
 SYSTEM_BUILDER_CONFIG: any = {  
...  
...  
paths: {  
'@amcharts/amcharts3-angular': 'node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts3-angular/umd/index.js',  
},
map: {
  '@amcharts/amcharts3-angular': 'node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts3-angular/umd/index.js',
},
```

Can anyone tell me how to get this right? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add following things in your `.ts` file.

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

And with class name add this

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {}
```

Comment: Thanks @The DIctator. It resolved my Lifecycle hook issue. Can you please help me out with the other error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Directive' of undefined ?

Comment: Yep cleared cache, reinstalled cli as well as node's different versions

Comment: Can you update your question with the screenshot of full error ? That would be great